# How to cache images properly in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, sdwebimage

I m using `SDWebImage` to cache image. But its not working. I am using it in this fashion under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[cell.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@app/media/access/pictures?p=%@",baseurl,data.picPath]]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"image_loader.gif"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

I suppose its downloading the images asynchronously. But my app freezes while scrolling the `UITableView`. And there is also network usage while scrolling up, for me that shouldn't happen as I am caching it.

Besides I have some logic to resize `UIImageView` frame according to image size under `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, could that be any reason???

```
if(data.type == 2)
    {
        height = 260.00;
    }
    else if(data.type == 1)
    {
        height = self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 115;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@app/media/access/pictures?p=%@",baseurl,data.picPath];
        self.img = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];


        if (self.img.size.width > CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)) {
            CGFloat ratio = self.img.size.height / self.img.size.width;
            return CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) * ratio+120;
        } else {
            return self.img.size.height+110;
        }




    }
```

Comment: Check the edited answer@Fay007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code below in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is causing issue:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@app/media/access/pictures?p=%@",baseurl,data.picPath];
        self.img = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
```

Code will executed every time you scroll tableView and it will cause freezing problem since it is not asynchronous call.

***Edit:***
To avoid that you can do something like this:

when finished downloading you can use,

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

This will call again

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Like,

```
[cell.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@app/media/access/pictures?p=%@",baseurl,data.picPath]]

                                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                                         if (error) {

                                             NSLog(@"error: %@",error.description);


                                         }
                                         else{

                                             //get image height and return this height from HeightForRowAtIndexPath
                                             Height=image.size.height;

                                             //reloading row will call heightForRowAtIndexPath,where now you can return height got above
                                             [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

                                             NSLog(@"Not an error in image download");
                                         }




                                     }];
```

***Edit1***:

to check image already cached, you can use below method of SDWebImage library:

```
- (BOOL)diskImageExistsWithKey:(NSString *)key;
```

***The cache key is an application unique identifier for the image to cache. It is generally the absolute URL of the image.***

Now if image exist in cache,then get image path using below methods of SDWebImage Library:

```
- (NSString *)defaultCachePathForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSString *)cachedFileNameForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

You can get the path to your image like this:

```
NSString *ImageKey;//key for the image you want the path for
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] defaultCachePathForKey:ImageKey];
```

in case you do not use the default location, you can use:

```
- (NSString *)cachePathForKey:(NSString *)key inPath:(NSString *)path;
```

For more detail check here: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: yes i understand the logic......but how to check if the image has already been cached so that i won't have to download it again

Comment: Great! enjoy coding@Fay007

Answer (score 3):

This is for sure:

```
self.img = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
```

Why are you downloading again the image? You should always use `SDWebImage`.

**ADDING**
Instead of doing

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@app/media/access/pictures?p=%@",baseurl,data.picPath];
self.img = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
```

You have to download the images before since the `heightForRow` won't wait for asynchronous blocks. Try to preload them using the `SDWebImage sharedDownloader`. They then will be in cache.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but how to call SDWebImage instead of  [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];